# Nginx + socketio: events not arriving

Tags: python, nginx, socket.io, gunicorn, flask-socketio

I want to send events to a flask server with socket io. But when I deploy my app via an nxginx proxy, the events don't arrive.

My Flask server app.py looks like this:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "this is the index function"

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    print('received message: ' + message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,debug=True)
```

Events are sent from the client like this:

```
 var socket = io('http://my.ip.address.it');
 ...
 socket.emit('message', 'here is my message 1');
```

This works when I deploy my server on localhost. But when I deploy it on a EC2 instance, via nginx, events emitted form a client only occasionally arrive.

My *nginx* proxy config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.ip.add.it;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io;
    }
}
```

And I start my server app like this:

```
gunicorn app:app -b 127.0.0.1:8000
```

How can I setup my Flask server correctly?

Comment: SocketIO automatically downgrades from websockets to long polling and then polling if it has problems. You might be able to tell from your SocketIO client in the frontend if this is taking place.

Comment: it seems like it does, as I am seeing: `POST http://my.ip.add.it/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LwVSz8l&sid=4c6a4a2ebb3a4faebfbf3c451924a1ac 400 (BAD REQUEST)` . When I disable polling, I am getting a websocket handshake error. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I would look at both /var/log/nginx/error.log and the gunicorn log (sent to stderr by default) and see if you can find this 400 error. If you find it in gunicorn, there should be a traceback or error message. If you don't find it in gunicorn, there might be something in the nginx error log which explains why the requests fails.

Comment: there is no access log entry, neither in gunicorn nor in nginx. any other ideas why I cannot connect to socketio?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Socket.IO configuration to nginx. See https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-nginx-as-a-websocket-reverse-proxy for the details, but here is the example from that link:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to add the Socket.IO part to the nginx config as suggested in the link you provided (see my edited post), but still get the same behavior. any ideas what I am still doing wrong?

Comment: You need to look at logs on the browser, nginx and server to see where messages get lost. Does the Socket.IO connection happen? If yes, does the upgrade to WebSocket happen?